# Xcode iOS Sprite Kit Game Doesn't Show Images on iOS 7 But Works on iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, image, ios7

I have uploaded a video to better explain my problem and to show you exactly what is happening.  Here is the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBmLqK4sqWc

I am making my first iOS game using Sprite Kit but can't seem to get the game working on iOS 7.  The game runs just fine on iOS 8.1 simulator and ever works on my actual device (iPhone 6) running iOS 8.

The problem is that images do not show on iOS 7.  They don't show on iOS 7 simulator and they do not show on an actual device running iOS 7, I tested it.

I don't think it has to do with the way I am naming the images because it works fine on iOS 8.  However, I am loading the images by dragging and dropping them into a folder in the project named images.  These images are named like image@2x.png then I load the images with the name 'image' as a sprite node.

Has any one had this issue before? What could be my problem?

Comment: It would be nice to know how you're using the images. Are they inside an asset catalog? Are they part of an atlas? Are they just PNGs inside a folder? I also had some trouble before when using iOS7 vs iOS8 with asset catalogs. I also wanted to know how you implemented the destruction of the little red ball where it splits into multiple smaller ones. Is that a particle emitter?

Comment: I drop in images into a folder and name them car@2x.png then load them with a spritnode with image named car

Comment: Can you post some of the code where you load the images?

Comment: _cannon =  [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Cannon"];
    _cannon.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width * 0.5, 0.0);
    [self addChild:_cannon];

Comment: Interesting behavior... Are the images .png's? Can you try using an .xcasset and post the results?