# When I use SKPhysicsBody(texture:size:) to create physics body I got an issue

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Everything works fine until I test my app on iPhone 5 or lower versions. I have this line

```
SKPhysicsBody(texture:size:)
```

crushing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

I run this on Xcode Version 7.1.1 (7B1005)
iPhone 5, iPhone 4s

[image]

and the console output is nothing.
But if I run it on iPhone 5s and higher so everything works fine.
What can be the problem?

Comment: Make sure your device is run on iOS 8.0 and later.

Comment: @WangYudong, this is simulator. Deployment target is 8.4

Comment: @wm.p1us What version of simulator do you use ? Which Xcode do you use ?

Answer (score 1):

**updated answer**

It seems to be a bug from Apple with simulators:

[SKSpriteNode can't load image from Images.xcassets in some iOS 9 simulators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33035819/skspritenode-cant-load-image-from-images-xcassets-in-some-ios-9-simulators)

[Xcode iOS Sprite Kit Game Doesn't Show Images on iOS 7 But Works on iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581147/xcode-ios-sprite-kit-game-doesnt-show-images-on-ios-7-but-works-on-ios-8)

**first answer**

```
if spaceShip.texture == nil {
    print("it is not nil")
}
```

Well... if you get the message, it means it IS indeed nil.

Maybe you got confuse :)

Comment: Did you clean build folder (do alt-shift-cmd-K), reset your simulators and even restart XCode ?
This kind of error (especially if it works on simulator 5s but not others) is often due to an old compilation which doesn't want to leave

Comment: Now i did everything as you said. But absolutely same result. 4s 5 - fail 5s and higher perfect.

Comment: I have a lot of code so it is better to give you whole project.
https://yadi.sk/d/BFx5LtxVkvJPV

Comment: so what should I do with it?

Comment: There's no solution, you can report a bug to Apple that's all

Comment: But users of iPhone 5 should have opportunity play games with correct physics body ?

Comment: I believe the problem is only for simulators, not for devices, you should try to find a real iPhone 5 and give it a shot

Comment: Not really. I don't have iPhone 5 , but some users took my code and had the problem above ( If someone here has iPhone 5 please test it for me %)